# Interactive text fields with Fabric.js( + React)

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I have the same code where I combined two rectangles and two text elements into a single large rectangular box. Initially, they are grouped together. However, I want each text box to become editable individually when clicked, and after editing, I want them to be regrouped.

However, I noticed that the box jumps to a different location, and I encounter the following errors:

Cannot read property 'getRetinaScaling' of undefined.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uniScaleKey').
My goal is to avoid these errors and enable the two text boxes to be editable when double-clicked, and then safely regroup them after editing.

```
onAddCombinedBox = (shapeProps: IShapeProps, canvas?: fabric.Canvas) => {
  const currUUID = uuid();

  const rectangle1 = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 40,
    height: 15,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 2,
  });

  const rectangle2 = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 15,
    left: 0,
    width: 40,
    height: 15,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 2,
  });

  const sensorName = new fabric.IText('Enter...', {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 900,
    fill: '#ffffff',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'FuturaBT-Book',
    editable: true,
  });

  const sensorValue = new fabric.IText('Enter...', {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 900,
    fill: '#ffffff',
    top: 15,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'FuturaBT-Book',
    editable: true,
  });

  const group = new fabric.Group([rectangle1, rectangle2, sensorName, sensorValue], {
    [SHAPE_POSITIION_X]: shapeProps[SHAPE_POSITIION_X],
    [SHAPE_POSITIION_Y]: shapeProps[SHAPE_POSITIION_Y],
    [SHAPE_SCALE_X]: shapeProps[SHAPE_SCALE_X] ?? 1,
    [SHAPE_SCALE_Y]: shapeProps[SHAPE_SCALE_Y] ?? 1,
    [UUID]: shapeProps[UUID] ?? currUUID,
  } as IGroupOptionsWithUUID);

  let lastClickTime = 0;

  group.on('mousedown', (options: fabric.IEvent) => {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const isDoubleClick = currentTime - lastClickTime < doubleClickThreshold;
    lastClickTime = currentTime;

    if (isDoubleClick && group && group.type === 'group') {
      const target = options.target as fabric.Group;
      if (target === group) {
        unGroup(canvas);
        target.getObjects().forEach((item: fabric.Object) => {
          if (item.type === 'i-text') {
            const textObject = item as fabric.IText;
            textObject.enterEditing();
            textObject.hiddenTextarea?.focus();
            textObject.exitEditing();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // TO DO : 수정 필요
  sensorName.on('editing:exited', () => {
    handleTextEditingExited(group, canvas, sensorName);
  });

  sensorValue.on('editing:exited', () => {
    handleTextEditingExited(group, canvas, sensorValue);
  });

  canvas?.add(group);

  // return currUUID;
};
```